# How can I redirect to a view with a parameter?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to follow the instructinons for [redirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) in Django. I want to redirect to a page and then redirect back again. Here's my code:

```
def home(request):
    current_user = None
    if 'user_id' in request.session.keys():
        current_user = request.session['user_id']
    else:
        return redirect('update_session_from_ldap', next='home')
def update_session_from_ldap(request,next):
    remote_user = request.META.get('REMOTE_USER', None)
    request.session['user_id'] = remote_user
    request.session.set_expiry(0) # Expire with browser session.
    return redirect('home')
```

When I go to the homepage, I get:

> NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for
>   'update_session_from_ldap' with
>   arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'next': 'home'}' not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the urlconf for the `update_session_from_ldap`.

Comment: Thanks, it's just `url(r'^ldap/$', 'library.views.update_session_from_ldap', name="ldap"),` - am I passing the parameter wrong? How can I pass the parameter directly to the view rather than in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what manji says, you need to either use the name of the URL, or the full function reference. You can't just use the last part of the function reference.

So, either:

```
return redirect('library.views.update_session_from_ldap', next='home')
```

or

```
return redirect('ldap', next='home')
```

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

what you're doing in the view is correct, it's just that the parameter `next` is missing from the url:

```
url(r'^/ldap/(?P<next>\w+)/$', 
    'library.views.update_session_from_ldap',
    name="ldap")
```

But I see that you're not using the `next` parameter in `update_session_from_ldap`. If you want to always redirect to 'home' and ignore `next`, remove it from the view and keep your original `url`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help - still get NoReverseMatch :( Re the next parameter: eventually I want to redirect to `next` dynamically - once I've figured out how to do the redirect at all...

Comment: To clarify a bit: with the URL change above, I can now do `/ldap/home` and have it redirect properly: what I can't do is call `return redirect('update_session_from_ldap', next='home')` without the same NoReverseMatch error.